# AWS lambda mp4 thumbnail generator using ffmpeg - incorrect format generated

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ffmpeg, aws-lambda, video-thumbnails

I am trying to create a thumbnail generator for every mp4 file uploaded to the s3 bucket. I have been following [this post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/media/processing-user-generated-content-using-aws-lambda-and-ffmpeg/) published by AWS. The code works fine for the transcoding video file. I changed the code to generate a thumbnail. The code does generate a file but it is an invalid image type.

```
import json
import os
import subprocess
import shlex
import boto3
import uuid

S3_DESTINATION_BUCKET = "example-bucket"
SIGNED_URL_TIMEOUT = 60

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    # s3_source_bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    # s3_source_key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    # s3_source_basename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(s3_source_key))[0]
    # s3_destination_filename = s3_source_basename + "_cfr.ts"
    
    hex_c = uuid.uuid4()
    s3_destination_filename = '/{}/{}.{}'.format('tmp',hex_c, 'jpg')
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    s3_media_url = 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/example-bucket/videos/presentations/testing.mp4'
    ffmpeg_cmd = "/opt/bin/ffmpeg -i \"" + s3_media_url + "\" -ss 00:00:02 -vframes 1  \"" + s3_destination_filename + "\""
    # ffmpeg_cmd = "/opt/bin/ffmpeg -i \"" + s3_source_signed_url + "\" -f mpegts -c:v copy -af aresample=async=1:first_pts=0 -"
    
    command1 = shlex.split(ffmpeg_cmd)
    p1 = subprocess.run(command1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
   
    resp = s3_client.put_object(Body=s3_destination_filename, Bucket=S3_DESTINATION_BUCKET, Key='{}{}'.format(hex_c, '.jpg'))
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Processing complete successfully')
    }
```

Output is as:

```
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "\"Processing complete successfully\""
}

Function Logs
START RequestId: b73aaacc-5da5-417a-9f98-5def438dee96 Version: $LATEST
ffmpeg version 4.1.3-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 20170516
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc-6 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gmp --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/example-bucket/videos/presentations/testing.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: isomavc1mp42
    creation_time   : 2020-04-17T18:31:33.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:33.07, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 90 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 854x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 427:240], 23 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-04-17T18:31:29.000000Z
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (HE-AAC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 64 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-04-17T18:31:29.000000Z
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> mjpeg (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0x67ddc40] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
Output #0, image2, to '/tmp/4633bb13-4a15-49b7-a445-d910bebaddf6.jpg':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: isomavc1mp42
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc), 854x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 427:240], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-04-17T18:31:29.000000Z
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 mjpeg
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
frame=    1 fps=0.4 q=6.3 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.03 bitrate=N/A speed=0.0149x    
video:14kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
END RequestId: b73aaacc-5da5-417a-9f98-5def438dee96
REPORT RequestId: b73aaacc-5da5-417a-9f98-5def438dee96  Duration: 6349.25 ms    Billed Duration: 6350 ms    Memory Size: 155 MB Max Memory Used: 123 MB Init Duration: 368.12 ms

Request ID
b73aaacc-5da5-417a-9f98-5def438dee96
```

An image file is uploaded to the S3 folder, but when I try to open it flags an invalid file format. The file size is only 40.0 Bytes.
[S3 bucket image folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtcIx.png)
[invalid file format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVnp8.png)

Comment: What does the "log" output from ffmpeg show?

Comment: Updated the code with log output from ffmpeg.

Comment: llogan, I tried this code locally and was able to generate the thumbnail. I think, I have narrowed down my problem with the above code. What is happening is that code is generating a thumbnail but I am passing the filename ( text if self, not an image object) as a body to s3 put_object function. Now my question is, how do I pass the thumbnail object to the s3?

Comment: I don't know, but the output from ffmpeg looks normal, and the file is ~14kB, so the log shows that ffmpeg is not the problem.

Comment: Appending '-f' and '-' to the ffmpeg_cmd fixed the issue. Thank you.

Comment: Since you found a solution feel free to make it an answer. Other users can upvote it and you can get more reputation so you have more access to other site features.

Comment: For reference to others doing work in this area - there is a very good reference at https://www.norrapscm.com/posts/2021-02-08-generate-thumbnails-in-lambda-from-s3-with-ffmpeg/ which utilizes an AWS premade lambda layer (see also https://serverlessrepo.aws.amazon.com/applications/us-east-1/145266761615/ffmpeg-lambda-layer )